# CodeIgniter PHP Exceptions

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've been wondering what's the best way to deal with exceptions on *CodeIgniter*. The usual way is to use `trigger_error()` or `log_message()`, however I've been wondering if there's a better way using try/catch.

Any tips or recommendations on how to implement this into *CodeIgniter*?

Currently I'm extending the `Exceptions Class`, but I would like to know if someone else already dealt with this problem before.

Comment: What sort of exceptions are you trying to catch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do something as simple as:

```
try { $this->load->model('modelname'); }

catch ( Exception $e )
{
    show_error($e);
}
```

If you application is [environment aware](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/news/2009/01/How-to-Support-multiple-production-environments-in-CodeIgniter) then I would show_error() on local, email error on live. This functionality could even be added into MY_Model to work generically for all models.

Comment: Not sure if this was correct in earlier versions of CI, but this doesn't work because `load()` will `show_error()` before the exception is caught.